# Start both applications and scripts using QProcess

Tags: qt

I have written this function to run scripts or applications:

```
void TerminalRun (QString command)
{
    QProcess process;
    process.start("sh",QStringList() << "-c" << command);
    process.waitForFinished(-1); // will wait forever until finished
}
```

It works just fine if I use it for applications like:

```
TerminalRun("geany &")
```

However, it can't execute scripts like:

```
TerminalRun("/path/to/script.sh &")
```

I don't get any error, but it just does not execute the script.

What is the issue and how can I fix it?

The script executes just fine directly in terminal.
I am using Qt 4.8 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Why would you start your commands with an '&' as parameter?

Comment: ...and why start each command under a new shell?  What *type* of script is `/path/to/script.sh`?  Are they executable in themselves?  That is, if you simply type `/path/to/script.sh` at the command line and hit `return` does it execute successfully?

Comment: @Jens '&' is to run the command or app in background.

Comment: @G.M. yes, if I type `bash /path/to/script.sh` in shell, it executes just fine.

Comment: If you need to type `bash /path/to/script.sh` rather than simply `/path/to/script.sh` then that suggests the script itself is not executable (i.e. does not have exec permissions).  If that's so then it can't be passed as an argument to `sh -c ...` -- hence your problem.

Comment: @G.M. this might not be entirely true. If I use `system()` instead of qprocess, it works just fine. I use it like `system("bash /path/to/script.sh &")`. But it does not work with qprocess.

Comment: Sure, but `bash /path/to/script.sh` as you pass to `system` and `sh -c /path/to/script.sh` as you use with `QProcess` are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @G.M. then what is your solution to have one function to execute both shell commands and applications?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not use "waitForFinished" but "start" and then the signals:

```
connect(&Process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(readyReadStandardError()));
connect(&Process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readyReadStandardOutput()));
connect(&Process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is related to my question!

Comment: I had the same problem and I have resolved it with this approach.
I understand that you prefer a blocking function using waitForFinished().